# Add packages using Directory.Build.Prop for .NET Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio solution where I am trying to add the Code Analyzers using build prop file in all projects. I have projects which depends on .NET Core as well as for framework. I have below Directory.Build.Prop file

```
<Project>
  <Choose>    
    <When Condition="$(UsingMicrosoftNETSdk) == 'true'">
      <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x86'">
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
        <RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory).editorconfig" Link=".editorconfig" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers" Version="5.0.1">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
      </ItemGroup>
   </When>
    <Otherwise>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
</Project>
```

Now, I am able to distinguish between the .Net core and framework projects using the property `UsingMicrosoftNETSdk` as all new core projects use SDK style of projects and that is not the case for Framework projects. But I am not exactly sure what should I add in the Otherwise section to add these analyzers to it.

As the used analyzer is platform independent, I am trying to use the package reference or reference element to add it. But it is not working as expected, and I see analyzer are not working, plus it messes up the other references in the Framework project( Get the warning sign on reference and project doesn't build) .

Also I think it has to do with package reference in framework project being managed in packages.config file, but I am not sure if we can apply something to it from build.props

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Actually**, .NET Framework projects support **PackageReference** NuGet management format. See [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#project-type-support).

And if you want to use `Directory.Build.props` file to install some NuGet packages with packages.config NuGet management format for .NET Framework projects, it is impossible because `packages.config` NuGet management format uses the `packages.config` to install packages, and `proj` file cannot modify `packages.config` file.

**But** only **PackageReference** NuGet management can use proj to install NuGet packages without `packages.config` file.

**Therefore**, the only consideration now is how to change the .NETt Framework project that has installed some NuGet packages using `packages.config`.

**Suggestion**

**Before** doing this, you could make a backup for all your projects.

**1)** So open all your .NET Framework projects on VS, and then right-click on every `packages.config` file-->click `Migrate packages.config into PackageReference`.

[image]

**Then**, all your .NET Framework projects could use **PackageReference** as .NET Core projects did.

**2)** Then, add these for .NET Framework projects on `Directory.Build.Prop` file like what you did for .NET Core.

```
<ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers" Version="5.0.1">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
 </ItemGroup>
```

**Update 1**

**Before** the process, you could make a backup for your solution.

==========================

**For ASP.NET framework projects**, it can use **PackageReference**. Just do some modification.

- First, unload these projects on the **Solution Explorer** and then open every csproj file of the ASP.NET projects.

Remember to comment the `ProjectTypeGuids` property like this:

[image]

- Second, then reload the projects and then you can migrate into **PackageReference**. Right-click on the `packages.config` and click `Migrate packages.config into PackageReference`.

**When** you finish this step, unload your project and make `ProjectTypeGuids` property back.

Try the following steps for every ASP.NET project.

=========================

**For C++ projects**, the NuGet package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers` is not suitable for them, so you have to make a judgement call to remove the C++ project from your current logic operation.

And C++ projects use `PlatformToolset` property to build projects, while .NET projects do not use it. So this is a good judgement condition.

Use this:

```
<Project>
  <Choose>    
    <!--exlcude c++ projects and all the net framework and net core projects can use PackageReference-->
    <When Condition="'$(PlatformToolset)'==''">
      <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x86'">
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
        <RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory).editorconfig" Link=".editorconfig" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers" Version="5.0.1">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
      </ItemGroup>
   </When>
    <Otherwise>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
</Project>
```

Comment: I am trying to do this, but one of the package says it is not eligible for this migration

Comment: Found the reason, its asp.net project... Migration is not currently available for C++ and ASP.NET projects. So, again, I am back to square one

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. And more info will help us resolve the issue more quickly. I have updated my answer, see `update 1`. More solutions has been provided.

Comment: Hey, the package did get ported the way you suggested, but when I build the project, it all package reference seems to vanish from the list

Comment: Could it be because of runtime entries in web config?

Comment: The `packagereference` node is under csproj file. Did  you know those nuget packages are missing on the reference list of solution explorer? If so, unload your project, then reload your project, use the detailed build log, and I can see the nuget packages under the output window. Make sure that there is no `ExcludeAssets` node under `packagereference` node of `csproj` file, make sure that there is no other restriction node on the `web.config` file.  If this do not help, share the `web.config` and the `packagereference` node of csproj file with us.